# Find constants in big/small O notation

Tags: real-analysis, limits, asymptotics

> Given the sequence $x_n=\frac{n}{n+1}$, find constants $a,b$ such that $x_n = 1 + O(n^{-a})$ and $x_n = 1+o(n^{-b})$

For $a$, I need

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x_n-1}{n^{-a}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{n}{n+1}-1}{n^{-a}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{-1}{(n+1)n^{-a}}\in\Bbb{R}$$ but I'm not sure how to proceed.

For $b$, I need

$$\dots=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{-1}{(n+1)n^{-b}}=0$$ Here I think it's enough that $b \leq 0$, but I'm not sure how to justify that.

Comment: If you are ok, you can accept the answer and set as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long divide to find, 
$$
x_n=\frac{n}{n+1}=1-\frac{1}{n+1}
$$
From which it is clear that 
$$
x_n=1+O(1/n)
$$
since 
$$
x_n-1=\frac{1}{n+1}\leq \frac{1}{n}
$$
for any $n$.

For the second part, you need some $b$ with 
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n^b}{n+1}=0
$$
but by inspection, you just need the order of $n$ in the numerator to be less than $1$. Indeed, $b=1-\epsilon$ for any $\epsilon>0$ will do.

Answer (score 1):

Note that

$$\frac{n}{n+1}=\frac{1}{1+\frac1n}=\left(1+\frac1n\right)^{-1}=1-\frac1n+\frac1{n^2}...$$

Or without Taylor's expansion

$$\frac{n}{n+1}=\frac{n+1-1}{n+1}=1-\frac{1}{n+1}$$

Thus

$$x_n=1+O(n^{-1})=1+o(1)=1+o(n^{-b}) \quad b\in[0,1)$$

Comment: Thanks! This question comes before Taylor sequences, so I think there must be a solution without them.

Comment: @ToddSewell ok I've update in a more simple way

Comment: How did the transition from $O$ to $o$ happen? I'm sorry for my dumb questions, this is really new to me.

Comment: @ToddSewell it a matter of definition. we say that $f(x)=o(g(x))$ for $x\to x_0$ if $f(x)=h(x)g(x)$ and $h(x)\to0$ when $x\to x_0$ that is if $f(x)/g(x)\to 0$.